# How to delete a specific tweet using Thujohn\Twitter package with Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-5

I am creating an application where the users connect their twitter account - store their access and secret token in DB. They are then presented with their tweets and can delete them.

I have used the Thujohn Twitter Package to get the user's tweets using their tokens. https://github.com/thujohn/twitter

However, I cannot use this package to delete a specific tweet.

My question is - How can I use this package to delete a tweet?

My code in my controller to delete a tweet is as such

```
function deleteTweet () {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $accessToken = $user->twittertoken;
    $accessSecret = $user->twittersecret;

    $request_token = [
        'token'  => $accessToken,
        'secret' => $accessSecret,
    ];

    Twitter::reconfig($request_token);
    $tweet_id = '777869567897038848';
    $tweets = Twitter::post("status/destroy/$tweet_id.json");

    var_dump($tweets);
}
```

I have filled the tweet id manually.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I regret to tell you that `thujohn/twitter` doesn't provide the function.
You can read the [source code](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter/blob/master/src/Thujohn/Twitter/Twitter.php) as a reference.